# Как запушить в Sourcetree (что делать с authentication helper)?

Tags: unity3d, git, source-tree

Я склонировал репозиторий из innersource с помощью Git. Теперь я хочу работать с ним через Sourcetree. Но когда я пытаюсь запушить изменения, я вижу всплывающее окно помощника по аутентификации, и я не уверен, что с ним делать. Если я отменю его - аутентификация не удалась.

Как я могу использовать или избежать этого всплывающего окна и использовать логин.пароль как в гите для аутентифиации?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Данное окно запрашивает тип хэлпера для хранения имени/пароля

Более детально читайте маны по гит, на предмет конфигурирования. Для системы в целом

> git config --global credential.helper

или только для текущего репа

> git config credential.helper

например тут
https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85

Comment: Спасибо, там написано как сконфигурировань это для гита, а как можно добавить это в Sourcetree? и можно ли обойтись без хелпера и просто ввести логин/пароль как через консоль гита только в Sourcetree?

Answer (score 0):

1. Установи двухэтапку в github
2. Открой терминал (мне так проще), создай запрос: $ git config credential.helper store
   *store не безопасно, лучше cache (Почитайте на хабре почему)
3. Установи https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases

Мне помогло!

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).